Converting .tex to .doc file
How can I change .tex file to .doc/docx file while maintaining formulas? I tried some online resources, but they can't fully translate from LaTex to a Word file.

there is no completely general conversion

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Have you tried pandoc?
